# Как заменить все элементы вида A на элементы типа B в строке c++

Tags: c++, форматирование

Есть строка вида

```
{000000}Равным образом {ffffff}постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности
```

Т.е. некоторые слова выделены цветом ( цвет распространяется до конца, пока его не перекроет следующий, а не на одно слово)

Как сделать строку вида:

```
<font color='000000'>Равным образом </font><font color='ffffff'>постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности </font>
```

Comment: Вы сами пытались выполнить задание? С какими сложностями столкнулись?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Держи) Скажи если что-то будет не так.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string formating(string & format) {
    bool first_time_flag = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < format.length(); i++) {
        if (format[i] == '{') {
            
            first_time_flag ? format.insert(++i, "<font color='") : format.insert(++i, "</font><font color='");
        }
        if (format[i] == '}') {
            format.insert(++i, "'>");
            first_time_flag = 0;
        }
    }

    format.erase(remove(format.begin(), format.end(), '{'), format.end());
    format.erase(remove(format.begin(), format.end(), '}'), format.end());
    format.append("</font>");
    return format;
}


int main()
{
    system("chcp 1251 > nul");
    string noFormat = "{000000}Равным образом {ffffff}постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности";
    //<font color='000000'>Равным образом </font><font color='ffffff'>постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности </font>
    cout << formating(noFormat);
}
```